# Override NetworkStream.BeginRead to get NetworkStream.ReadAsync overridden

Tags: c#, asynchronous, stream

I want to implement a network client that handles some specific protocol. The easiest option I see is to write `NetworkStream` descendant class that processes protocol-specific features. So I created class with sample protocol: all data is transferred wrapped into `[[` and `]]`. Client must receive it transparently.
As a simplest server I run ncat with the following command line

```
>echo [[pong]] | ncat -l -p 2222
```

and here's the program (don't judje it too tough - it's a sample and I'm just learning C# - awkward clauses possible)

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// Sample network stream that wraps all sent and received data into "[[" and "]]"
class MyNetworkStream : NetworkStream
{
  public MyNetworkStream(Socket socket)
    : base(socket)
  {
  }

  public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
  {
    // Read and unwrap
    byte[] wrapperBuf = new byte[2];
    byte[] contentBuf = new byte[count];
    base.Read(wrapperBuf, 0, wrapperBuf.Length);
    int res = base.Read(contentBuf, 0, contentBuf.Length);
    contentBuf.AsSpan(0, res - 2).CopyTo(buffer.AsSpan(offset));
    return res;
  }

  public override IAsyncResult BeginRead(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
  {
    throw new Exception("BeginRead is called"); // doesn't happen!
  }
}

namespace HelloWorld
{
  class Program
  {
    static async Task MainAsync()
    {
      Socket sock = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
      await sock.ConnectAsync("localhost", 2222);
      MyNetworkStream stm = new MyNetworkStream(sock);
      byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
      int read = await stm.ReadAsync(buf.AsMemory());
      Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf.AsSpan(0, read))); // prints "[[pong]]"
    }

    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
      // Main async loop
      MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
  }
}
```

I succeeded in overriding sync `Read` but I want async as well. From what I've read in some articles and also in the [sources](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,f956b0c07e86df64) overriding Begin* should be enough to have *Async working. But it's not: exception is not risen and `[[pong]]` is written to console so none of my custom methods is called.

(**solved, see edit below**) I also tried overriding ReadAsync:

```
  public override Task<int> ReadAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    throw new Exception("ReadAsync is called"); // doesn't happen
  }
```

but it doesn't get called either.

The questions:

- What I'm doing wrong in overriding?
- What's the proper way to achieve what I want? Wrapper class inherited from Stream having NetworkStream instane as internal field?

==== Edit ====

issue with ReadAsync was solved by overriding the proper overload.

```
  // NetworkStream has 2 ReadAsync overloads directly calling undeluying socket methods instead of
  // referring to BeginRead so we have to override them both.
  public override Task<int> ReadAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
  {
    return this.ReadAsync(buffer.AsMemory(offset, count), cancellationToken).AsTask();
  }

  public override ValueTask<int> ReadAsync(Memory<byte> buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
  {
    throw new Exception("ReadAsync is called");
  }
```

initial issue was solved with the hint from
Fildor (NetworkStream doesn't call Begin* from its *Async overrides). However I'll likely rework my design to another principle as Markus suggested.

Comment: https://source.dot.net/#System.Net.Sockets/System/Net/Sockets/NetworkStream.cs,6006b93b3942e29b => from line 506 : ReadAsync does not call BeginRead. It uses the underlying socket, directly.

Comment: @Fildor damn I must be using older FW version (it says 4.8). I wonder what's the difference between source.dot.net and referencesource.microsoft.com and which version uses the former.

Comment: Ah, so you are on Dotnet Framework 4.8 ?

Comment: @Fildor nope, I'm on 6 but the sources browser which I stumbled upon was pointing to 4.8 (IDK how to change the version)

Comment: Anyway I still can't get why my `ReadAsync` override doesn't work either.

Comment: Are you calling the correct overload? (The one you have overriden?)

Comment: Ahh, I got it. It calls another overload with Memory argument!

Comment: `public override ValueTask<int> ReadAsync(Memory<byte> buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)` <= this one, I guess.

Comment: use https://source.dot.net for .NET core / 5+,
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/ is for .NET framework.

Comment: @KieranDevlin OK, got it!

Answer (score 1):

As you'd already proposed, I'd also vote for creating wrapper class that holds a `(Network)Stream` and by that following the principle "composition over inheritance". Why?

Inheritance is a very strong relationship. As your example and the search for which `ReadAsync` method to override shows, you depend on the implementation of the base class and that it calls the respective `ReadAsync` overload. If the base class changes this later on, your code might not work anymore.

If using composition on the other hand, you rely on the outer interface of `(Network)Stream` and are much more flexible. Instead of changing the behavior of `NetworkStream`, you might be able to create a class, that uses a generic stream as an input and does not rely on `NetworkStream`.

```
public class MyNetworkStream : Stream
{
  private readonly Stream _underlyingStream;

  public MyNetworkStream(Stream underlyingStream) 
  {
    _underlyingStream = underlyingStream;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Thus, you could inject (pass a constructor parameter) any stream into the class and are not restricted to always use a `NetworkStream`. This might proove valuable when testing the functionality of your stream.

Above example derives from `Stream` as you proposed. The `Stream` class is a common denominator so that you can use your class in a variety of scenarios. However, you need to implement the complete interface of a `Stream`.

If you want to have a more minimal interface of the class, you could omit inheriting from `Stream` and create an interface for the class that reflexts exactly the needs of your scenario.

Besides streams, there are also the `*Reader` and `*Writer` classes in the `System.IO` namespace. From a conceptual point of view, your wrapper class could be a `MyProtocolReader` that holds a reference to a stream, reads and adjusts the retrieved contents (e.g. remove the leading and trailing parentheses).

Comment: I could also imagine a "MyProtocolClient" similar to "HttpClient".

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I just wanted to avoid so much wrappers (there will be TcpClient that will hold MyNetworkStream that will hold NetworkStream that will hold Socket... ough). But probably I just have to make MyClient containing Socket and NetworkStream and doing stuff inside its methods. I can't vote answers up yet but my appreciation is real ;)

Comment: @AntoniusHart you're welcome. Thanks for the appreciation - btw, now you can vote up ;-)

Comment: @Markus still can't :( It requires 15 , I only have 11 thanks to you :)

Comment: I'm content with the appreciation :-) have a nice day!